# Converting parseable struct to codable doesnt work as expected

Tags: swift, codable

I would like to parse the response from a service using codable which is parseable now. The current structure is  as below

```
{
    "service": {
        "categories": [
        {
        "categoryName": "category1",
        "fullName": "Federico",
        "id": "12345",
        "phone": "9787678684"
        }
        ],
        "type": "type"
    }
}
```

My problem is, I am not getting error messages sent by server which  will be in the format as below

```
{
   errorType: “some errorType”,
   errorMessage: “some error message”
}
```

How can I make the model which is codable which satisfies these?

Comment: Can you show us the `JSON`? Also, please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have updated my question with sample json.

Comment: Can you show me the current model you have created?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
struct General: Decodable {
 let service: Service?
 let error: Error?
}
struct Service: Decodable {
 let categories: [Categories]
 let type: String
}
struct Categories: Decodable {
 let categoryName,fullName,id,phone: String
}
struct Error: Decodable {
 let errorType,errorMessage: String
}
```

Now, you can check if there is error or not.

```
guard let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(General.self,from: data) else { print("Unable to parse response"); return }
if json.error.isEmpty {
//Show error
} else {
//Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are getting different *JSON* response in case of success and failure, you need to create 2 models,

**1. Success Models**

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let service: Service
}

struct Service: Decodable {
    let categories: [Category]
    let type: String
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let categoryName, fullName, id, phone: String
}
```

**2. Error Models**

```
struct Error: Decodable {
    let errorType: String
    let errorMessage: String
}
```

Now, **parse** the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    let error = try JSONDecoder().decode(Error.self, from: data)
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable solution is an enum with associated types, the benefit is you get rid of optionals

```
enum Response : Decodable {

    case success(Service)
    case failure(ResponseError)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let responseData = try container.decode(Service.self)
            self = .success(responseData)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let errorData = try container.decode(ResponseError.self)
            self = .failure(errorData)
        }
    }
}

struct Service : Decodable {
    let categories : [Category]
}

struct ResponseError : Decodable {
    let errorType, errorMessage : String
}

struct Category : Decodable {
    ...
}
```

And use it

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    switch result {
        case .success(let service): print(service)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
} else {
    print(error)
}
```